# Вывести заказы интернет магазина в админку на php

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте! Я новичок. Пишу магазин на PHP. Все сделала, но не получается вывести заказы для просмотра.

Код прилагаю. Пишу на примитивном процедурном php даже без функций, потому что и так не могу понять, как правильно все вывести.

Есть 2 таблицы:

1. Таблица заказов `orders` с полями

   - id_order
   - name_order (имя заказчика)
   - e-mail (мейл заказчика)
   - phone
   - address
   - customer (номер заказа из сессии)
   - id_good (id товара)
   - quantity (кол-во товара)
   - datetime (дата заказа)
2. Таблица товаров `good`, в которой находятся `id_good`, `name_good` и другие поля.

Я хочу вывести заказы таким образом:

```
Идентификатор заказчика: 18qskgmvp0i4133sbqfct1c0j3
Имя заказчика: Коля
E-mail: kolia@mail.ru
Телефон: 99999999999999
Адрес: г. Воркута, ул. Медведей, 77
Дата заказа: 31-08-2016 19:21:37

Наименование товара: Товар 4 Категория 1
Количество: 4
Цена: 5 руб.
Сумма: 20 руб.

Наименование товара: Товар 3 Категория 1
Количество: 1
Цена: 4 руб.
Сумма: 4 руб.
```

А у меня получается вывести только так:

```
Идентификатор заказчика: 18qskgmvp0i4133sbqfct1c0j3
Имя заказчика: Коля
E-mail: kolia@mail.ru
Телефон: 99999999999999
Адрес: г. Воркута, ул. Медведей, 77
Дата заказа: 31-08-2016 19:21:37

Наименование товара: Товар 4 Категория 1
Количество: 4
Цена: 5 руб.
Сумма: 20 руб.

Идентификатор заказчика: 18qskgmvp0i4133sbqfct1c0j3
Имя заказчика: Коля
E-mail: kolia@mail.ru
Телефон: 99999999999999
Адрес: г. Воркута, ул. Медведей, 77
Дата заказа: 31-08-2016 19:21:37

Наименование товара: Товар 3 Категория 1
Количество: 1
Цена: 4 руб.
Сумма: 4 руб.
```

Как вывести заказы, что реквизиты заказчика повторялись один раз, а под ними выводились все заказанные товары?
Код ниже:

```
global $link;
$sql_order = "SELECT * FROM orders"; // вывод данных заказчика
$query_order = mysqli_query($link, $sql_order) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$num_order = mysqli_num_rows($query_order);

for($i = 0; $i <= $num_order; $i++){
    $row_order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_order);
    echo '<h4>Идентификатор заказчика: '
    .$row_order['customer'].'<br />Имя заказчика: '.$row_order['name_order'].'<br />E-mail: '.$row_order['email'].'<br />Телефон: '
    .$row_order['phone'].'<br />Адрес: '.$row_order['address'].'<br />Дата заказа: '.date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $row_order['datetime']).
    '</h4>';
    echo '<br />';  
    $id_good = $row_order['id_good'];

    $sql_good = "SELECT * FROM goods WHERE id_good = '$id_good'"; // вывод товаров
    $query_good = mysqli_query($link, $sql_good) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while($row_good = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_good)){
        echo 'Наименование товара: '.$row_good['name_good'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Количество: '.$row_order['quantity'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Цена: '.$row_good['price_good'].' руб.';
        echo '<br />';
        $sum = $row_good['price_good']*$row_order['quantity'];
        echo $sum.' руб.';
        echo '<br />';                  
    }
    echo '<hr />';

}
```

Comment: Дам совет - начните карьеру правильно: учите паттерны, ООП помогает, сборщики используйте и т. д. Не надо начинать путь программиста вниз. Такой код разве что в 90-х был нормален и дело не в новичке.

Comment: Чтобы учить сложное, нужно понять простое. Я процедурный стиль еще не поняла, а ООП для меня вообще темный лес.

Comment: Было бы неплохо если б вы какой-нибудь http://sqlfiddle.com/  закинули   те две самые структуры таблиц и хоть каких-то тестовых данных

Comment: На совсем тестовых данных все работает нормально  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/03hr-m90n   ....... возможно дело в том что надо не `$i <= $num_order;` писать, а `$i < $num_order;` ...... но для точности нужны конечно демо данные таблицы........... что-то типа такого http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db6c7

Comment: Я такое код никогда не писал, ну да ладно. Я просто к тому, что многих и это устраивает, подобный код даже в массовых и популярных продуктах есть (привет, WP). Не хотелось бы чтобы новичок посчитал это нормой.

Comment: @Other Зачастую такой код работает гораздо быстрее навороченных ООП решений. Простые вещи надо решать простыми средствами.( Хотя вот прямо тут со скоростью конечно проблемы. Запрос в цикле чтения другого запроса. Надо бы одним запросом ...) И если новичек начнет с паттернов высока вероятность, что дальше он будет мыслить только этими паттернами и какие то нестандартные решения, значительно лучше решающие задачу он просто не придумает

Comment: @Mike, я не предлагал выключить мозг, лишь то, что необходимо развивать навыки, особенно, если это нужно, т. к. в данном коде оптимизаций можно сделать много.

Comment: Торжественно клянусь изучать ООП. Высылаю ссылку с БД: https://yadi.sk/d/ZopincPTui3S5

Comment: Посмотрел вашу БД ... Вы хотите вывести заказаз и под ним _все товары_ то есть предполагается, что товаров несколько... При этом у вас в _заказе_ хранится некий `id_good`, который есть идентификатор _единственного_ товара (в таблице goods, как и следовало ожидать, это первичный ключ, т.е. уникальный). Таким образом у вас в заказе физически не может быть более 1 товара. По хорошему надо хранить не id товара в заказе, а в товарах хранить id заказа. Хотел написать уже ответ по поводу того, что все можно легко сделать одним запросом к БД, но ответ неинтересный выходит, товаров то нет ...

Comment: @Mike тут либо костылем в строке заказа в поле `id_good` должны идентификаторы через запятую быть, либо вообще отдельную таблицу `orders_goods` чтоб связать..... **Anastasia** - в вашем случае получается так выводить строки потому, что немного неправильная структура в бд. нужно либо как написал **Mike** сделать и тогда увязать... либо скорее промежуточную таблицу делать

Comment: Я почему-то думала, что поле customer, куда приходит номер заказа, т.е уникальный номер сессии и будет уникальным для товаров в заказе. Только не получается додуматься, как по нему вытащить эти товары.

Comment: А еще у вас количество товара непосредственно в заказе. т.е. база в принципе не рассчитана на то, что бы в заказе было более одного товара. Я видел у вас там еще корзина есть, так там та же проблема, в корзине может быть только один товар. В общем БД спроектирована не верно

Comment: @Mike А можете наставить на правильный путь и расписать как правильно сделать структуру для этого и что куда положить? Можете править мой ответ. Я сделал его общим специально.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Написал про заказы. по поводу данных заказчика, про которые вы там написали. В общем оно конечно так, только надо разобраться какие поля должны быть у заказчика, а какие оставить в заказе. Адрес доставки при одном заказчике может отличатся от заказа к заказу, так же контакты встречающего заказ человека. Если бы я делал серьезную систему такого плана я бы наверное адреса заказчика хранил бы в отдельной таблице (что бы он мог выбрать один из списка или добавить новых) и в конкретном заказе ставил id адреса. но для небольшой системы кажется излишним

Comment: @Anastasia посмотрите ответ. В принципе, с текущей структурой получится как-то так. Про структуры таблиц и нормализацию и пр. стоит еще больше где-то почитать изучить

Comment: Я посмотрела. Большое Спасибо за помощь! Вроде бы все работает.

Answer (score 2):

В текущем виде можно сделать только так:

достать не повторяющихся заказчиков из `orders`, потом выбрать все заказы из таблицы `orders` присоединив данные о товаре. Затем в цикле пробежаться по всем заказчикам и внутри уже по всем заказам. Если идентификатор заказчика совпадает - то выводим информацию. Причем если это первая строка - то выводим в начале инфо о заказчике. Это выглядит ну жуууууууууутко костыльно и ужасно, но лично я с текущей структурой БД не смог придумать ничего лучше.

```
global $link;
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM orders';
$customers = [];

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $customers[] = $row['customer'];
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);    
    /*
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($customers);
    echo '</pre>';
    */
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN goods USING(id_good)';

$orders = [];
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $orders[] = $row;
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);    
    /*
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($orders);
    echo '</pre>';
    */
}

foreach ($customers as $customer) { 
    $k = 0;

    foreach ($orders as $order) {           
        if ($customer == $order['customer']) {
            $info = '';
            if ($k == 0) {
                $info .= '<h4>Идентификатор заказчика: '.$order['customer']
                .'<br />Имя заказчика: '.$order['name_order']
                .'<br />E-mail: '.$order['email']
                .'<br />Телефон: '.$order['phone']
                .'<br />Адрес: '.$order['address']
                .'<br />Дата заказа: '.date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $order['datetime'])
                .'</h4><br />';                             
            }           

            $info .= 'Наименование товара: '.$order['name_good']
            .'<br />Количество: '.$order['quantity']
            .'<br />Цена: '.$order['price_good'].' руб.'
            .'<br />'.($order['price_good'] * $order['quantity']).' руб.<br /><br />';    

            echo $info;

            $k++;
        }           
    }

    echo '<hr />';
}
```

пощупать можно тут: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p9dg-mqbi  Нажав на <kbd>Run</kbd> (я добавил еще заказов от юзера 123)

Вообще структуру БД надо бы менять. Например в `orders` поля данные о заказчике излишни. Они там не должны находится. Должен быть только идентификатор заказчика. А его данные уже должны быть в таблице `customer` например.
В общем при различных улучшениях и реструктуризации БД возможно можно в один запрос всё уместить и проще работать.

**UPD** (от @Mike):
При текущей структуре БД в одном заказе физически не может быть более одного товара. Так как ID товара и его количество находится непосредственно в таблице заказов. Предлагаю следующие изменения:

1. Из таблицы `orders` удалить колонки `id_good` и `quantity`
2. Создать таблицу "Товары в заказе":

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_goods` (
     `id_order` int NOT NULL,
     `id_good`  int NOT NULL,
     `quantity` int NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`,`id_good`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES orders(`id_order`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`id_good`)  REFERENCES goods(`id_good`)
   )
   ```

Тогда запрос для получения одновременно заказов и товаров в них будет такой:

```
select O.*, T.quantity, G.price_good, G.name_good
  from orders O
  left join order_goods T on T.id_order=O.id_order
  left join goods G on G.id_good=T.id_good
```

На выходе он даст столько строк с заказом, сколько товаров в заказе (или 1, если товаров нет).

Comment: Алексей, вы -  гений! Еще раз благодарю вас за правку кода. Если я могу вас как-то отблагодарить, скажем, бросить вам платеж на телефон или на электронный кошелек, то сообщите мне.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае у вас повторяется весь цикл столько раз сколько товаров, а вам нужно сделать цикл в конструкции if.
Из разряда: if существует заказ выводим(проверяем sql запросом он у вас уже есть):

```
`$row_order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_order);
echo '<h4>Идентификатор заказчика: '
.$row_order['customer'].'<br />Имя заказчика: '.$row_order['name_order'].'<br />E-mail: '.$row_order['email'].'<br />Телефон: '
.$row_order['phone'].'<br />Адрес: '.$row_order['address'].'<br />Дата заказа: '.date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $row_order['datetime']).
'</h4>';
echo '<br />';  
$id_good = $row_order['id_good'];`
```

А дальше в теле этого-же if ставим ваш цикл for(с теми-же условиями которые есть) он уже будет перебирать только товарные позиции, а шапка будет одна.